# SQL Query to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to convert this query to LINQ to use with Entity Framework 4.

```
Select *, 
(select SUM(Of_Orders.Contribution) from Of_Orders
where Of_Orders.CauseID = Of_Causes.CauseID) AS Earned
FROM Of_Causes
```

Can anyone help me to do this.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cools like the CauseID field represents a foreign key? If it does then you can map an association in your entity model, so that `cause.Orders` is a property you can access. Side note, you can also rename the entities/properties, they don't have to match table names so you could get rid of the ugly underscores! That would then look like this:

```
var result = from c in context.Of_Causes
select new {cause, cause.Orders.Sum(o => o.Contribution}
```

You'd get a few benefits from doing that (if you can), like a cleaner model, and more efficient SQL queries being generated.

If you can't use a foreign key, I'd join the tables manually which again should help performance.

I believe that would look like this but my translation from VB to C# may be dodgy, here's the C#:

```
var context = new ModelContainer();
var result = from c in context.Of_Cause
             join o in context.Of_Orders on c.Id equals o.CauseID into g
             select new {Cause = c, Total = g.Sum(o => o.Contribution)};
```

And here's the VB original in case my translation is off!

```
Dim result = From cause As Of_Cause In context.Of_Cause
             Group Join order As Of_Orders In context.Of_Orders On order.CauseID Equals cause.Id Into total = Sum(order.Contribution)
             Select New With {.Cause = cause, .Total = total}
```

Comment: Hi, thats a cool explanation. Can you help me with onemore thing whenever we do "select new" it creates an anonymous type. I want to create a list of type Cause and want to store the Total in a property of Cause object how should I do that?

Comment: Yep, no problem, but could you ask it as a new question? Can't easily do much in a comments box other than comment as there's no code etc.

Answer (score 1):

That would be something similar to:

```
from cause in context.Of_Causes
select new {
    cause,
    Earned = context.Of_Orders.Where(o => o.CauseID == cause.CauseID).Sum(o => o.Contribution)
};
```

I've made some assumptions about the types involved, but that should be easy for you to work out.

Comment: That is sth I have already done but the "select new" is creating an Anonymous Type but I want to create a List of Cause type.